# How do I run man without using sudo and not under root directory?

Tags: linux, root, manpage

I've encountered a problem that I can't seem to find a solution for. Running the `man` command anywhere that isn't in ~ or without using sudo returns:

"/usr/bin/man: can't execute less: Invalid argument

/usr/bin/man: command exited with status 255: ..."

I've tried running `export MANPAGER=less`

`$PAGER` and `$MANPAGER` are set to less. It still does not seem to work.

What do I do?

Edit:
After further review I've noticed that the command works everywhere except a mounted network directory that I use. I can use `less` and `echo`man ls`` just fine, but just using `man` as usual brings up the mentioned issue.

Comment: What is the output of `which less`?

Comment: The output is: /usr/bin/less

Comment: Does the less command work properly when you run it outside of ~ or without sudo?

Comment: Yup, it works just fine.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you run `man` after setting MANPAGER to something else, for example: `export MANPAGER=more`?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same problem. "man: can't execute more: Invalid argument".

Comment: There might be a problem with permissions, permissions in the manpages should be 644 (-rw-r--r--). Can you run `ls -l /usr/share/man/man1/xz.1.gz` to check?

Comment: Just checked: the permission is set to -rw-r--r-- properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the permission and ownership of /usr/bin/man. Make it so that it is executable by everyone.